# ASP.NET Membership Provider detached from a site

Tags: asp.net

I'm making a webservice that acts as user authentication module. You can add roles, users, update them and see if a user can connect to given username / password, if it's logged and so on.

Various applications would connect to the webservice in order to centralize user management.

I'm thinking of using ASP.NET's own Membership Provider classes (and ASPNETDB) as it seems to have most of what i'm looking for.

My problem is that most of the configurations have to be done in web.config (like the connection string to ASPNETDB, addictional user properies etc). Being a webservice, I do not need the configurations to access the webserice, I want to do all the operations (authentication, administration) programmatically.

Is this possible? How? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to roll your own Membership/Role Providers. See this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WSSecurityProvider.aspx) for an example.